# Does this price elasticity depend on p?

Tags: elasticity

I'm studying for a test I have this week and a practice question asks whether or not the price elasticity of demand for the demand function $\ q = Ap^{-x} $, where A and x are positive constants depends on the price **p**.

I've attempted to use the equation, $ \frac{dQ}{dP}*\frac{P}{Q} $ in order to solve the problem and I am getting the result,

$ \epsilon = \frac{-xA}{p^{x+1}}*\frac{p}{q} = \frac{-xA}{p^{x}q}$

Which would mean that the elasticity does  depend on **p**, however the answer in my practice exam says that it does not depend on **p**. Why is that the case/where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That type of demand is called an [Isoelastic demand function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoelastic_function), because the elasticity of demand is constant, so it **does not** depend on prices.

You have not done any mistake. But you just need to move forward one more step. Notice that at the moment your derivative has both p and q in it. **Try to get rid of q**. This is, try to have $\epsilon=f(p)$, and not $\epsilon=f(p,q)$. This hint should be enough for you to solve the question.